# C++ stringstream adding extra bytes

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

I'd like to start with the fact that I'm still learning C++ and some of the things still baffles me.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to build a byte stream to send over a socket. I'm trying to create a packet 1536 bytes in length for a handshake

```
std::stringstream s1Stream;
char randData[1528], zeroVal[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
memset(&randData, 1, sizeof(randData)); // Fill the buffer with data

s1Stream << timestampVal; // 4 bytes
s1Stream << zeroVal; // 4 bytes
s1Stream << randData; // 1528 bytes
```

When I convert s1Stream to string and check the size() of that string the program says that the size is **1541**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::stringstream`'s `operator<<(char const*)`, which is used here, treats its argument as zero-terminated C-style strings, and your `randData` array is not zero-terminated.

Since `randData` is not really a C-style string and looks like it could end up containing null bytes, the fix is to use

```
s1Stream.write(randData, sizeof(randData));
```

Note that this problem applies with `zeroVal` as well, except nothing of `zeroVal` will be written to `s1Stream` because it is zero-terminated at the first byte.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm :) Will accept your answer once StackOverflow allows me to!

Comment: The real question is why he's using `std::stringstream` to begin with.  The abstraction of the iostream classes is textual formatting; if you're not doing that, then they probably aren't the right tool.